# Polymer background-color of host element

Tags: css, polymer, polyfills

I'm using [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org) for a new version of my website and I'm having some issues with displaying a data-bound background-color in all browsers.

[Here is a live example](http://jsbin.com/hipahehuviru/1/edit). In Chrome it works as one would expect, with a red background-color showing up (depicted in the image below)

[image: Background color showing in Chrome]

Now, in Firefox and IE 11 the background-color does not show up, resulting in something like this:

[image: Background color not showing in Frefox and IE]

Now, I expect this has something to do with the polyfill, since Chrome is the only browser to natively support custom elements as shown [in the browser compatibility page](http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/compatibility.html)

Here's my code (same as in live example):

```
<polymer-element name="leiding-card" attributes="bgColor">

      <template>
        <style>
          :host{
            display: block;
            position: relative;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 2px;
            background-color: {{bgColor}};
          }
          .profilePic{
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            margin: 10px;
            background-size: 50px 50px;
          }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="default_styles.css">

        <paper-shadow z="1" animated="true"></paper-shadow>
        <div class="white">
          <content select="h1"></content>
          <template repeat="{{p in people}}">
            <div layout horizontal wrap around-justfied>
              <div class="profilePic" center style="background-image: url({{p.profilePic}});"></div>
              <div style="margin-right: 10px;">
                <p>{{p.name}} {{p.lastname}}</p>
                <h4>{{p.email}}</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </template>
        </div>

      </template>

      <script>
        Polymer('leiding-card',{
          ready: function(){
            this.people = [
              {name: "John", lastname: "Snow", profilePic: "http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-3.jpg", email: "john.snow@john.snow"},
              {name: "Other", lastname: "Bastard", profilePic: "http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-640-480-8.jpg", email: "other.bastard@other.bastard"}
            ]
          }
        });
      </script>

    </polymer-element>
```

I've already tried doing stuff like `polyfill-next-selector { content: ':host'; }`, but I can't really find an example of it online and usually I don't see any issues with directly applying styles to the `:host`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an open bug around bindings not working in style tags under the polyfill - https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/270. Looks like there's a workaround provided in the bug notes, see http://jsbin.com/pelon/1/edit